Problem mapping OIDC and OAuth 2.0 concepts to my application
I am trying to implement an SSO server so that my ASP.NET Core MVC applications can:

Authenticate users with the SSO server
Get the user's roles and claims from the SSO server
Every T minutes I want my MVC app to check with the SSO server to see if the user is still logged in and if their roles and claims has changed.

These are the 3 important objectives that I want to achieve in my implementation.
I want to use OpenIddict in my implementation. But I am getting confused how the concepts of OIDC and OAuth 2.0 apply to my scenario.
As my objective should somehow be achieved through the mechanisms of OAuth 2.0, I read a few articles about OAuth 2.0 and made a list of concepts in it and tried to map them to my scenario. Here is what I came by:

Resource Owner: In this case it must be the user.
Client: It must be my MVC app.
Authorization Server: My SSO server.
Resource Server: Again my MVC app?
Authorization Grant: I really don't know what it is in my scenario
Redirect URI: An address on my MVC app that user will be redirected to after login on the SSO server.
Access Token: Does it make sense in this scenario? As the resource server and the client are the same? Is there a need for it?
Refresh Token: Used for refreshing the Access token, but as I am not sure if the access token is needed at all here I don't know if it is going to be useful in my scenario.

Still I don't see how I can achieve the 3 goals above.
So my question is how I can achieve the 3 objectives stated in the beginning of the question using OAuth 2.0 and OIDC? How can my MVC application get the required the roles and claims of the user through OAuth 2.0 mechanisms? What are the concepts and mechanisms that I am missing?

Sounds like you currently use apps with a cookie based session. Those apps would use the authorization code flow to initiate user authentication and then store tokens in cookies once it completes. Eg you might use the Microsoft OpenID Connect middleware.
The grant is the actual token issuance, called the authorization code grant in this flow. In some use cases, the resource owner grants a third party access to their resources, though for a normal app you may not need that and the grant is automatic when the user logs in.
Each app can use its own cookies to know if the user is logged in. You could send the access token to the authorization server's OpenID Connect userinfo endpoint to get the user's latest claims. If the access token expires you would use the refresh token to get a new one and then retry the request.
FUTURE
Really though, OAuth is an authorization protocol centred on API usage via access tokens. So in the longer term you might extract logic from your web apps into APIs (resource servers).
This might allow you to share API logic between apps, or develop single page applications and mobile apps that call the same APIs.
OAuth should result in scalable security, where the difficult security is externalized from apps, to simplify their code, and they also have access to up-to-date security. Eg the authorization code flow can enable logins via passkeys or digital wallets.
